# Where does the test user find the app

Tags: facebook

I created a simple facebook app and test user account. When I log in using the test user I don't see where I should find the app to open for testing. Please help.

Comment: What platform …?

Comment: App that runs inside facebook. It is supposed to display content from an external website within a facebook page.

Comment: Well then you first of all have to install/add the app on the page ... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Comment: You are a star my brother. Thank you very much. I am answered.